# How does cross validation work with MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mapreduce

As you know it is possible to use Python from within Pig or Hive on a Hadoop cluster. One example is machine learning which includes cross validation for model optimization.

A Hadoop job is mapped to a number of nodes that perform their tasks after which the results are reduced. If I were to perform cross validation on Hadoop: How is mapping taken care of without splitting the cross validation set to different nodes that then train their separate models on incomplete cross validation sets?

Thanks for your input!